# Deny tabs closing in Android Browser

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, jquery-dirtyforms

I have a php page form  containing only text fields.

In this page i have an 'insert' button which when clicked insert into my database any data that was insert in the form.

I want that if a user insert data and tries to leave the page without clicking the 'insert' button, that they would be prompted that the page contains unsaved changes and they would be asked to verify if they want to leave or not.

I've tried to implement it by javascript OnBeforeUnload, OnUnload, JQuery [dirtyforms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) and they works perfectly in any browser, but when i try to close a page in a android browser(the platform i use to insert data) nothing is displayed.

How can i deny the tabs closing in android?

Comment: Which browser are you testing in, exactly? A quick search revealed [this on the Google forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/7yrDfBiufrY) as a bug report for mobile Chrome.

Comment: Tested with Firefox 28, Android Browser and Mobile Chrome. I knew the chrome bug, but other browsers ignore the OnBeforeUnload too...

Comment: Seems Maxthon being the only browser who support the OnBeforeUnload function